# Which field should I use for getting the income yield of this bond ETF?

Tags: etf, bonds, yield, fixed-income, bond-etf

I am looking at "iShares Global Corp Bond UCITS ETF" listed on the London Stock Exchange. On the website for this bond ETF, there are fields like;

- "distribution yield"
- "flat yield"
- "Weighted Avg Coupon"
- "Weighted Average YTM"

I would like to know the income yield of this bond ETF if I were to buy it today. Which of these fields is the right one to get the income yield? Income yield is what I would get as income in percentage in the next 12 months if I were to invest in the bond today.

This is the website for this bond ETF.
https://www.ishares.com/uk/individual/en/products/251813/ishares-global-corporate-bond-ucits-etf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is the distribution yield, which is 2.65. You can see the yield on FT as well, which is listed as 2.64. The difference between the 2 values is likely to be due to different dates of updates.

http://funds.ft.com/uk/Tearsheet/Summary?s=CORP:LSE:USD